# Can autoencoders take time series into account?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection, autoencoder

[Here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/off-the-beaten-path-htm-based-strong-ai-beats-rnns-and-cnns-at-pr), I read the following:

> The first key to understanding is that HTM relies on data that streams
>   over time (...) By contrast, conventional deep learning uses static
>   data and is therefore time invariant.  Even RNN/LSTMs that process
>   speech, which is time based, actually do so on static datasets.

On the other hand, [on](https://towardsdatascience.com/extreme-event-forecasting-with-lstm-autoencoders-297492485037) I read the following:

> We can assert that our LSTM Autoencoder is a good weapon to extract
>   importan unseen features from time series

What is true now? Are [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) or [autoencoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) or combined suitable for time series analysis? Or is [HTM](https://numenta.com/) better suited for that purpose, indeed?

The main purpose is to detect anomalies emerging through time before they happen.